# Sample extraction from Excel dump

Tags: excel, bigdata, vba

I want to extract data from a dump excel file as sampling. Dump file has around 20,000,00 lines which includes duplicates entries as well and I want 500 unique samples out of dump file. Data should be extracted proportionately as per each line processed. (e.g. if person A has processed 1500 lines, sampling data extracted for person A should be proportionate to his processed lines and sampling data size i.e 500).

Can anyone help me with automation VBA coding for this, I searched a lot on google to find a solution could not get any details. Also manual extraction of data takes around 4 to 5 hours.

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself yet?? If not, simply googling your problem or asking a question here won't help!

Comment: I'd suggest filtering  your data to each individual, copying that data to a second sheet, removing the duplicates and then getting the sample.  So try searching "excel vba filter", "excel vba removeduplicates"

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do:

- first, **find a way to read the dump file**. Read the 50 first lines and load them to a new file. If you do not manage to do this and get error, open a new question and show us your code
- second, **evaluation function**: <strike>calculate the ratio per person, store it somewhere, a simple tab might be handy for a start but slow, and create a function to which you'll give a person name, and will return true/false depending on the person's name with probability (same as above, write something and come back to us with factual issue)</strike>  you can use a random value between 0 and 1, and if it is above threshold `[desired sample size]/[number of lines]`, then add to sample file: no need for an evaluation function, the more occurrences of the user you have in the original file you have, the more you have in the result sample.
- then your good, you **read every line, call above function** on person's name you find on the file, and if function return's true, you add the line to sample file.